# Why is ggplot using default colors when others are specified?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I am trying to have ggplot2 show one line of a histogram as a different color than the rest.  In this I have been successful; however, ggplot is using the default colors when a different set are specified.  I am sure there is an error in my code, but I am unable to determine where it is.  The data and code are below:

## create data

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(71185)
dist.x <- as.data.frame(round(runif(100000, min= 1.275, max= 1.725), digits=2))
colnames(dist.x) <- 'sim_con'
```

## start histogram

```
ggplot(dist.x, aes(x = sim_con)) +
geom_histogram(colour = "black", aes(fill = ifelse(dist.x$sim_con==1.55, "darkgreen", "firebrick")), binwidth = .01) +
theme(legend.position="none")
```

Which results in the following image:
[image]

I do not want to use the default colors, but instead want to use 'darkgreen' and 'firebrick'.  Where is the error in the code?  Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can explicitly set colors in `aes`; you need to do it in `scale_fill_manual`, as in the example below:

```
ggplot(dist.x, aes(x = sim_con)) +
  geom_histogram(colour = "black", binwidth = .01,aes(fill=(sim_con==1.55))) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('TRUE'='darkgreen','FALSE'='firebrick')) +
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You're so close!

In your code above, ggplot is interpreting your fill as variables in your data set - factor `darkgreen` and factor `firebrick` - and doesn't have any way of knowing that those labels are *colors*, not, say, names of animal species.

If you add `scale_fill_identity()` to the end of your plot, as below, it will interpret those strings as colors (the *identity*), not as features of the data.

One benefit of this approach vs @marat's excellent answer above: if you have a complex plot (say, using `geom_segment()`, with a starting value and an ending value for each observation) and you want to apply two fill scales on your data (one scale for the start value and a different scale for the end value) you can do the conditional logic in the data processing step, then use `scale_fill_identity()` to color each observation accordingly.

```
ggplot(
  data=dist.x,
  aes(
    x = sim_con,
    fill = ifelse(dist.x$sim_con==1.55, "darkgreen", "firebrick")
  )
) +
geom_histogram(
  colour = "black",
  binwidth = .01
) +
theme(legend.position="none") +
scale_fill_identity()
```

Comment: A highly informative explanation.  I think that both yours and Marat's answers solve the present problem well.  Your explanation is great to understand the magic behind the grammar and for future applications.

Comment: Understanding non-standard evaluation in R has really helped me get my head around what is happening inside of some packages in the hadleyverse: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html  glad this was helpful!